# 'Error: Not implemented: window.open ' in Jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

1. Navigate.ts

```
const NavigateToOtherSite = (url: string) => {
  window.open(url, 'blank');
};
export default NavigateToOtherSite;
```

2.App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import NavigateToOtherSite from './Navigate';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div data-test='id-1' onClick={() => NavigateToOtherSite('https://fast.com/')}>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

3.App.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as Navigate from './Navigate';

it('should open correct website', async () => {
    let test = jest
      .spyOn(Navigate, 'NavigateToOtherSite')
      .mockImplementation();
    const wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
    wrapper.find('[data-test="id-1"]').simulate('click');
    expect(test).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Need to write unit test to check  'NavigateToOtherSite' called and with proper parameter. Not sure why fails and throws error 'Not implemented: window.open'

Failure:

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

window error:
unit test throws error
console.error
Error: Not implemented: window.open

Comment: @Konrad suggestion helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
it('should open correct website', async () => {

const jsdomOpen = window.open; // remember the jsdom open

 window.open = jest.fn(); // implementation for window.open

    const wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
    wrapper.find('[onClick]').simulate('click');

    expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'https://fast.com/'',
      '_blank'
    );

    window.alert = jsdomOpen;
  });
```